# Concatenate two Scala mutable maps preserving the keys of the first map

Tags: scala, scala-collections

The scala API let's you append one map to another as follows:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.{Map => MutableMap}
val m1: MutableMap[Int,String] = MutableMap(1 -> "A", 2 -> "B", 3 -> "C")
val m2: MutableMap[Int,String] = MutableMap(2 -> "X", 3 -> "Y", 4 -> "Z")
m1 ++= m2 // outputs: Map(2 -> X, 4 -> Z, 1 -> A, 3 -> Y)
m1        // outputs: Map(2 -> X, 4 -> Z, 1 -> A, 3 -> Y)
```

The behaviour is to override the repeated pairs with the pairs coming from the right map.

What is a good way to do it in the opposite way? That is, concatenating the pairs of `m1` and `m2` in `m1` where the pairs of `m1` are kept if repeated in `m2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store as a list (or similar collection) and group them:

```
val l1 = List(1 -> "A", 2 -> "B", 3 -> "C")
val l2 = List(2 -> "X", 3 -> "Y", 4 -> "Z")

(l1 ::: l2).groupBy(_._1) //Map[Int, List[Int, String]]
//output: Map(2 -> List((2,B), (2,X)), 4 -> List((4,Z)), 1 -> List((1,A)), 3 -> List((3,C), (3,Y)))
```

You can of course remove the leftover integers from the Map's value lists if you want.

Answer (score 2):

`m1 ++= (m2 ++ m1)` perhaps?
Do you *have* to mutate `m1` (that's rarely the right thing to do in scala anyway)? 
You could just create a new map as `m2 ++ m1` otherwise ...